# Android App - Fires onCreate whenever bluetooth keyboard connects / disconnects

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, keyboard, barcode-scanner

I have a fairly simple android app, which uses a bluetooth barcode scanner connected to it.

The problem I'm having, is that whenever the bluetooth scanner connects or disconnects from the android device (as it does when it goes to sleep/wakes up), it causes the onCreate method of the active window/layout to be called.

Is there some way I can stop this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your activity is being restarted, because the connection of the scanner (which appears to your Android device as a keyboard) is considered a configuration change.

I would **strongly** recommend that you modify your app so that any data is properly cached and restored when your activities are restarted - just like when the screen is rotated. Then connecting and disconnecting the scanner will not impact your users.

Alternatively, you can [tell Android that your app will handle "keyboard" configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) and it will *not* restart your activities when the keyboard connects/disconnects. However, it will still restart your activities for all the other configuration changes that you do not handle - and the [list of configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) is kind of long.

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed correct I think. I used this guide to help me handle the runtime changes: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject